# Java Basic Object Program

Tags: java, object

I don't understand why it doesn't give a random amount. Please explain.

Thanks :)

my code(learned from tutorial):

```
public class day5 {
    int totalwater = 0;

    public day5(){
        //default constructor
    }
    public day5(int wateramount){
        totalwater = wateramount;
    }
    // don't need static in Object. It will be used in other classes.
    public void addwater(int amount){
        totalwater = totalwater + amount;
    }
    public void drinkwater(int amount){
        totalwater = totalwater - amount;
    }
    public int getwater(){
        return totalwater;
        //because we are going to return an integer, public "int" and "return"
    }
}



public class day5obtest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        day5 waterbottle = new day5(0);
        int rand = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        waterbottle.addwater(rand); 
        waterbottle.drinkwater(rand);
        System.out.println("The amount of water in your bottle now is: " + waterbottle.getwater());
    }
}
```

Output:

The amount of water in your bottle now is: 0

Comment: Are you expecting the amount of water to have changed after calling **drinkwater()** ?

Answer (score 5):

You add and drink the same amount. You have to generate a new random amount after adding, like this:

```
    int rand = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    waterbottle.addwater(rand); 
    rand = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    waterbottle.drinkwater(rand);
```

Comment: Oh! I understand now! Thanks very much. I feel dumb xD

Answer (score 1):

You only generate one random number.

You add a randomly generated number to the amount of water, but then you remove that same number from the amount of water, so there's always a net change of 0.

To fix this you could create a second random number rand2 and remove that from the amount of water in drinkwater()

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a good practice to begin you class name with uppercase like `Day5`.
2. Add getters and setters in your `Day5` class therefore you can access their fields outside.
3. If you want to make your program more realistic, add a test in your `drinkwater` method

as follow

```
public void drinkwater(int amount){
    if(amount<=totalwater)
        totalwater = totalwater - amount;
    else 
        System.out.println("amount bigger than total water");
}
```

4. Make new random amount after adding water.

Finally

```
 int rand = (int)(Math.random()*100);
 waterbottle.addwater(rand); 
 rand = (int)(Math.random()*100);
 waterbottle.drinkwater(rand);
```

Comment: You have a point there, this way negative result can be avoided.

Comment: it is logic that we cannot drink more than we have ;) @TamásG.